# How can I double click to open Nautilus folders in a new window instead of a tab?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, nautilus, mouse

I want to be able to shift-double click to open a folder in a new window rather than a tab. Currently, both shift-click and control-click open into new tabs.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I find it easier to drag files to a window rather than a tab's title when I want to use the mouse (otherwise I'd use mv).

I know I can get a new window by right clicking and selecting "Open in new window". That's not the solution I'm after.

I'd also like to be able to customize whether that new window becomes active or not by holding down different keys.

Thanks!

Comment: I see no ways to change that. Likely hard coded. This would constitute a valid feature request.

Comment: Alright, I submitted it: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/807